# How to query data from SQLlite in Tab Fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

there is some good practice of how populate Tab Fragments with a SQLlite query? I’m using Compatibility library v4 to implement a Tabbed, using fragments on devices running Android 2.1 or higher.

Thanks for your help.

```
package br.com.log2br.tabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import br.com.log2br.R;

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // query data?

        return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container, false);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need [create your database](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/) ojbect (for example DatabaseHandler) and the constructor needs a context, each fragment has getActivity method.

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
```